# How do i fix the "Faild to update Android SDK package list" when building a android apk problem in unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, build-error

When i try to build my Test Scene with just a cube and a plane to an apk I get the error "Faild to update Android SDK package list. See Console for details!".

I have tried to reinstall unity, add the sdk, ndk modules for android and I tried to unseleckt all checkmarks in Edit>Preferences>External Tools, restart unity, play the game in the editor and then build but it also didnt work.[image: these are the errors i see in console!]